# Android Virtual Device Manager

Tags: android, virtual-device-manager

I've made a simple hello world app in Eclipse and would like to run this on the Android Emulator.  I thought this would be simple!  However every time I run this the emulator-arm.exe keeps bailing out.

I've tried changing the RAM values as suggested in other posts; removing and adding snapshots (tick box); tried changing the device, target and cpu platforms; running eclipse as administrator; installing the new Android Studio; I've also tried running the device from the command prompt.

I'm currently running this on a Windows 8 machine (surface RT Pro 64 bit) if that helps...

Does anyone have a stable setup for an emulator that I could try?

I've been searching for hours now how to solve this problem so hopefully someone can help?

Windows Application Event Error:

Faulting application name: emulator-arm.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x51e43d2d
Faulting module name: ig7icd32.dll, version: 9.17.10.2867, time stamp: 0x50635085
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0003b60e
Faulting process ID: 0x1318
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce8ab69269dfdd
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator-arm.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ig7icd32.dll
Report ID: d05157b1-f6a9-11e2-be79-6045bdf21239
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Post your emulator setting, maybe we can figure something out. Also make sure you update to the latest version.

Comment: AVD Name: Mytest; Device: Nexus 7(7.27", 800 x 1280: tvdpi); Target: Android 4.3 - API Level 18; CPU/ ABI: ARM (armeabi-v7a) Keyboard: Hardward keyboard present (ticked); Skin: Display a skin with hardware controls (Ticked); RAM 256 VM Heap 32; Internal Storage: 200; Snapshot (unticked); Use Host GPU (Unticked)

Comment: I think the RAM is way too low, the real N7 has 1GB RAM, and I don't even think there's any 4.x device with less than 512MB RAM. Try increase it to 1GB and see if it helps.

Comment: I've increased it 1024 and still comes up with the same error.

Comment: I have to say that I am stumbled. Another method is if your CPU supports it, you can download Intel's 4.2.2 x86 emulator and see if it works.

Comment: Yes I will give that a go and see how I get on.  You can see why I've posted this on here.  In theory it should just work ... :-)

Comment: Yeah, don't worry, it's quite normal to get all kinds of..."fun" issues developing for Android. It might also be incompatibility with Windows 8, so I would try it on a Win 7 box if possible.

Comment: Thanks @kai for your suggestions.  I've just tried installing Eclipse, adt etc onto another Windows 8 machine (32 bit this time) and the emulator works without a problem.  It must be something to do with the Windows RT surface pro that it doesn't like.  I'm going to reset it to factory setting and start again...  Again thanks

Comment: Glad to be of help ;)

Comment: OK it's now working.  I've reinstalled my PC and it's now working....how odd!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run AVD from eclipse , you need to install plugin.
Below link will guide you.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: I've already got the ADT installed and setup.  It's just the Emulator within the Virtual Device Manager that isn't working.

Comment: @user2517884 It's good that you are trying to help a fellow, but it's better to read the question carefully in order to give an answer that is pertinent to the question. Just a head's up.

Answer (score 0):

update your graphics driver, its caused due to opengl. ig4dev32.dll is intels graphics driver's module. I had the same problem. And now every thing is fine after updating the  drivers.